# Opening WinForms window in Inno Setup not working on older Windows versions

Tags: c#, winforms, inno-setup, dllexport, pascalscript

I have an Inno Setup script where the desired form was too complicated to build entirely in Inno Setup itself, so I created a helper class library in .NET which contains a WinForms window with the things I need.

I open this WinForms window in Inno Setup by exposing the method with the [Unmanaged Exports NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnmanagedExports) from Robert Giesecke.

This works perfectly on my development machine running Windows 10. It also works on a test server running Windows Server 2012 and 2016. When I try to run the setup on a Windows Server 2008R2 machine however, I am presented with the following error:
[image: Sytem.ArgumentException: Font '?' cannot be found.]

Sytem.ArgumentException: Font '?' cannot be found.

This is my Inno Setup script:

```
#define MyAppName "InnoTest"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "Test"
#define MyAppURL "http://inno.test"

[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
OutputDir=C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_inno
OutputBaseFilename=test_inno_setup_x64
Compression=lzma/Max
SolidCompression=true

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\InnoTestNet\InnoTestNet\bin\Release\InnoTestNet.dll"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
procedure ShowTestForm(); external 'ShowTestForm@files:InnoTestNet.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  ShowTestForm();     
end;
```

and my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;

namespace InnoTestNet
{
    public class InnoTestNet
    {
        [DllExport("ShowTestForm", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static void ShowTestForm()
        {
            try
            {
                var testForm = new TestForm();
                testForm.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have reduced the WinForms window down to the bare minimum (just one label).

Things I have tried:

- Embedding "Arial.otf" in the class library, loading the font at
  runtime with PrivateFontCollection and setting the font on the
  WinForm.
- Using another font like Calibri or Tahoma
- Changing the font of the InnoSetup installer itself (DefaultDialogFontName)
- Executing "Application.EnableVisualStyles()"

The Windows Server 2008R2 environment is a fully updated clean install with .NET Framework 4.7.2 intalled.

The class library is targeted for .NET Framework 4.5.2.

I am using the Unicode version of InnoSetup 5.6.1.

*edit*

I found this interesting SO question:
[Using SetDefaultDllDirectories breaks Font handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818073/using-setdefaultdlldirectories-breaks-font-handling)

It appears, when calling the "SetDefaultDllDirectories" function from the Windows API, font resolving might get broken.
When further tracking down the [release notes of Inno Setup 5.5.9](http://www.jrsoftware.org/files/is5.5-whatsnew.htm) it appears Inno Setup is indeed calling this problematic function.

Comment: Can you run your form directly without Inno (in test application)?

Comment: Yes. I made a console application and referenced the class library from there. Ran without any problem on all systems.

Comment: My guess is Inno Setup is calling a windows API function which breaks the font resolving. But don't know where to look. I also came across this interesting SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818073/using-setdefaultdlldirectories-breaks-font-handling

Comment: What if you run that console application from Inno Setup?

Comment: Also this post suggests the error can be caused by Antivirus: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/36ab500f-4d38-418f-97f5-dfece24c281f/quotsystemargumentexception-font-cannot-be-foundquot-during-application-start-up-any?forum=winforms - Can you try disabling it?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl calling the console application from inno setup will probably work fine. Might go this way if I'm unable to find a more elegant solution. There is no antivirus present on the machine. I have found some new clues and edited the question.

Comment: Try to build dll with target x86 (Inno setup is 32-bit application only). As an other option, if exe file runs from setup correctly, consider to use it instead of library.

Comment: @Miamy I am already building the class library as x86. Might go the exe route if I'm unable to find a more elegant solution.